# The multiple Parent-child search about Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In the multiple Parent-child search.I am very Worried.please see the img .

Help me! Help me! please me! SOS, In the year, I want to have a new begin.

[image]

Please tell me why I can't search the data I want by the below the relationship.

I am waiting for your best answer!

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your search as such:

```
GET /family/father/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
       "type": "son",
       "query": {
         "term": {
            "name": "value" <-- give the value to be matched
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

**OR** what if you use the `match` keyword:

```
GET /family/father/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "son",
      "query": {
        "match": { <--- change this from term to match
          "name": "the value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.But I has try it before .It has also searched nothing. I do not kown why. as you see in the image. if you have time,I hope you can help me . I am alse analysing it.

Comment: Of course ,you can try again,I know you are skilled about elasticsearch.But sometime The fact is different from what you think.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you,I had tried some times before,but I will try it again.How can I connact with you in real time，because I offen come across some unexpected problems . I am also happy to have a sincere 、 skilled and foreign friend!

Comment: Oh ,thank you edit it for me. Before some days my manager had said that I want to use elasticsearch like database and link some types :one to one、one to many.Can I do it ?

Comment: You have to use something like [Parent-Child Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html#parent-child-mapping).

Comment: Yeah ,I had done it as you seem in the image .but it only can search one type every time ,if I like three or more types ,there have many problems .